# Replace elements in array by values from other array

Tags: php

I have main array:

```
$main = array(
    'city' => 'London',
    'street' => 'Hyde Park',
    'name' => 'John'
);
```

And examples:

```
$example1 = array(
    'city',
    'name'
);

$example2 = array(
    'city',
    'street',
    'name'
);
```

I would like to receive (by single array):

```
$example1 = array(
    'London',
    'John'
);

$example2 = array(
    'London',
    'Hyde Park',
    'John'
);
```

Is better way for this than:

```
        function newArray($mainArray, $array) {
            $new_array = [];
            foreach ($mainArray as $key => $main) {
                if (in_array($main, $array)) {
                    $new_array = $key;
                }
            }

            return $new_array;
        }
```

?

Maybe I can use array_map or array_walk, but how?

Comment: Are you sure your code works? It looks like it assigns a string to an array and it's overwritten on every iteration anyway. Also using in_array here is inefficient. But otherwise the premise of looping through the arrays isn't wrong, doing it more "elegantly" in a single line isn't going to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested, `array_map` is good for this.

```
$example1Mapped = array_map(function($key) use ($main) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $main) ? $main[$key] : $key;
}, $example1);

$example2Mapped = array_map(function($key) use ($main) {
    return array_key_exists($key, $main) ? $main[$key] : $key;
}, $example2);
```

Another approach could be to use a combination of `array_flip` and `array_intersect_key`

```
$example1Mapped = array_intersect_key($main, array_flip($example1));
```

`array_flip` will turn the values of an array into keys and its key into the values. So `$example1 = ['city', 'name'];` will be turned into `$example1 = ['city' => 0, 'name' => 1];`

`array_intersect_key` then will remove all values from `$main`, which keys are not present in the flipped `$example1`.

Yet this solution will not keep the order of the values, but instead enforce the order of the `$main` array.

If there are values in your example arrays, that are not present as keys in the `$main` array the values will be kept in the `array_map` approach, while they will be removed in the second approach.